# How to enable forward search in Adobe Reader from TeXnicCenter?

Tags: pdf, search, latex, adobe-reader, scrolling

I am creating a LaTeX document in TeXnicCenter with LaTeX => PDF profile. There is a feature which allows to open and scroll auto-generated PDF to the paragraph that is under the cursor in TeXnicCenter. This works with Sumatra PDF and the feature is called "Forward search" in Profile settings, "Viewer" tab. I would like to have the same feature with Adobe Reader.

Is this possible at all? Do I have to use "command line" or "DDE command" setting? What do I have to fill in "Command", "Server", "Topic" fields in the Profile settings?

Comment: I will offer this as a comment.  When faced with issues from TeXnicCenter.. RUN AWAY SCREAMING.  Use TeXlipse, its much better!

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out. Meanwhile you can offer this as answer. Maybe I will mark it if I'll like TeXlipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the best tool that I have found so far is TeXworks. It has convenient interface, forward and backward search and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with this list of DDE messages accepted by Acrobat, provided by Adobe:

[DDE Messages](http://snipurl.com/umtg0)

Look at particularly `DocGoTo`

---

Also look at [this blog post](http://adventuresindevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/texniccenter-dde-commands-for-acrobat.html) which does the same thing you want to do. And [this Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=uFt&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&ei=VdePS7iuFdCRjAeh6vzFDw&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CAUQBSgA&q=texniccenter+acrobat+dde&spell=1).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately `DocGoTo` allows only to show  certain page in the document, which does not make any sense for TeXnicCenter (there is not page layout in the original document).

Comment: The blog post talks about Acrobat Reader, while I have Adobe Reader. First is not free, while second is freely available.

Comment: Adobe Reader = Acrobat Reader = Adobe Acrobat Reader. The 'Reader' part is the free part. Acrobat Standard / Pro are the commercial versions: http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/ and http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/

Comment: Thanks for explanation but the solution still doesn't help my problem.